# JScrollPane scrollbar doesnt appear automatically

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I created a `JScrollPane` with a `JTextArea` as `Viewport`.
I set the Size of the `JTextArea` with `.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320,180));`

Then I set the Horizontal and Vertical ScrollBar Policy to `SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED`. But when I get to the end of the `ScrollPane` they don't appear automatically :/

I already tried to set them `ALWAYS`- they appear then but I am not able to scroll with them...

```
JTextArea ta0 = new JTextArea();
JScrollPane p0;
ta0.setEditable(true);
ta0.setLineWrap(true);
ta0.setWrapStyleWord(true);
ta0.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320,180));
p0 = new JScrollPane(ta0);
p0.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
p0.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
```

Comment: What is the size of the JScrollPane that appears? Is it 320 x 180? If so then no Scrollbar will appear. As you have fixed the size of the JTextArea.

Comment: yeah the size of JTextArea is fixed ... but it looks stupid if I make it dynamic size :( is there an other way? to make it fixed size but with scrollbars?

Comment: my bad... i just set the preferredsize of the JScrollPane instead of the JTextArea and now it works - thanks anyway

Comment: set size to the JScrollPane and remove the size from JTextArea. After this the display would be of fixed size but the JTextArea size would be dynamic.  In other words the text area could go on increasing in size where as the view port would be of fixed size.

Comment: *"I set the Size of the JTextArea with .setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320,180));"* - That's you're problem right there, use `JTextArea#setRows` and `JTextArea#setColumns` to effect the preferred size of the component while allowing it to change to meet the needs of it's content